# How to configure .yaml in azure devOps using Appium?

Tags: continuous-integration, android-emulator, azure-pipelines, appium, appium-android

error:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/session. The exception message was: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:4723)
----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:4723)

Answer (score 0):

The error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" means that your request got through, so it is caused by firewall.

This message means that no application listens to this port. Make sure your server application is running and that it listens to the right port number (and IP address).